# laravel5: route to error 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, laravel-5.3

I tried to add a route for the error 404:

```
Route::get('404', function()
{
    echo "404";
    return "404";
});
```

but I have this error with "laravel/framework": "5.3.*":

Trying to get property of non-object

How can I display an error message or render a view ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any route for 404 error.

Just create a view at

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

And in that view, write the message you want to show on 404 error